# What is the process involved in registering custom functions at runtime?

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I am creating an Excel add-in and one of the features that we'd like to give our users is to let them create custom functions that are registered and added at runtime.

I understand how to create custom functions at design time by adding entries to your manifest and pointing to the javascript file that has the function and the json file that contains the definition of the function.

I see that Script Lab has the ability to add / register functions at runtime and was hoping that someone might be able to explain what needs to happen behind the scenes in talking with office.js or point me to a relevant tutorial on how that is completed.

Comment: You may find more information [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime)

Comment: Dynamic registering Custom Functions is not supported yet except Scriptlab.

Answer (score 1):

It's not officially supported, but I've tried it, and it works like this:

1. Create your custom functions metadata, manually like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json) or automatically with [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-functions-metadata#generate)
2. Call `Excel.CustomFunctionManager.register(myMetadataJsonString, '')` like [Script Lab does](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/8ac068bd1d562089161b5b2ed6cc0d429850e58f/packages/editor/src/pages/CustomFunctions/components/App/utilities/index.ts#L44)
3. Call `CustomFunctions.associate("ID_FROM_METADATA", myFunction)` for each function

For example:

```
  // This might optional, but it seemed to only work once the taskpane had been opened
  await Office.addin.showAsTaskpane();

  await (Excel as any).CustomFunctionManager.register(
    JSON.stringify({
      functions: [
        {
          id: 'say_hi',
          name: 'say_hi',
          description: 'Returns a greeting',
          parameters: [],
          result: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    ''
  );

  CustomFunctions.associate('say_hi', () => 'hi');
```

Comment: How were you running the code above? In your task pane or...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes in the taskpane using a shared runtime.

Comment: I put this in my functions json in case the shared runtime didn't start automatically, it gives the user a hint to force it.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/office-js/custom-functions.schema.json",
  "functions": [
    {
      "id": "please_open_taskpane",
      "name": "please_open_taskpane",
      "description": "Open the taskpane to load all custom functions",
      "parameters": [],
      "result": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score -1):

Here is the script lab source code[a link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab) you can refer to. Hope can help.